# Java cannot find symbol when compiling

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am following a Java tutorial (left to my own devices to write the test code), but when trying to compile I get a symbol not found error. I've looked and looked, but cannot work out why the code I have written produces this error. It's probably very simple, but I'd appreciate someone pointing out the cause as I'm pulling my hair out trying to understand what I've done wrong!

TestBeerExpert.java:

```
package com.example.model;

import com.example.model.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestBeerExpert {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestBeerExpert test = new TestBeerExpert();
        test.go();
    }

    private void go() {
        BeerExpert expert = new BeerExpert();
        List<String> brands = expert.getBrands("amber");
        ...
    }
}
```

BeerExpert.java:

```
package com.example.model;

import java.util.*;

public class BeerExpert {

    public List<String> getBrands(String color) {
        List<String> brands = new ArrayList<String>();
        ...
        return(brands);
    }

}
```

Directory structure:

`beerV1 -> src -> com -> example -> model -> TestBeerExpert.java & BeerExpert.java`

Compiling from `beerV1` with `javac -d classes src/com/example/model/TestBeerExpert.java`

And the actual error:

```
src/com/example/model/TestBeerExpert.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        BeerExpert expert = new BeerExpert();
        ^
  symbol:   class BeerExpert
  location: class TestBeerExpert
src/com/example/model/TestBeerExpert.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        BeerExpert expert = new BeerExpert();
                                ^
  symbol:   class BeerExpert
  location: class TestBeerExpert
2 errors
```

For the life of me I can't work out what I'm doing wrong. The files are in the same directory and package, so as far as I am aware this should be compiling. I'd be grateful to now only have the code corrected but and explanation of what I have done wrong so I can remember it for the future. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you compiled BeerExpert first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `src` to your *sourcepath*

```
 javac -sourcepath src -d classes src/com/example/model/TestBeerExpert.java
```

You need to do this because you execute `javac` from a different directory from where the sources are.

No need to compile `BeerExpert` first (javac will do it for you with the above command).

Validatation:

```
~/beerV1$ ls src/com/example/model/
BeerExpert.java  TestBeerExpert.java
~/beerV1$ ls classes
~/beerV1$ javac -sourcepath src -d classes src/com/example/model/TestBeerExpert.java
~/beerV1$ ls classes/com/example/model/
BeerExpert.class  TestBeerExpert.class
```

Comment: Why would one have the directory containing the `.java` files in the classpath?

Comment: Thanks, that works a treat. I would not have figured that out on my own. It also turns out that I need to specify the classpath when running the test also (that was another painful Internet search, you'd have thought I'd have cottoned on to that after the compiling issues...)! Much appreciated.

Comment: @RohitJain You were right. The correct thing is to add _src_ to the _sourcepath_. Classpath also works, but it seems wrong conceptually. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the compile error because compiler is not able to find BeerExpert class. Try below
1. first compile BeerExpert.java using :
javac -d classes src\com\example\model\BeerExpert.java
2. then compile TestBeerExpert.java 
javac -cp classes -d classes src\com\example\model\TestBeerExpert.java